# How do I get SMTP server for JavaMail?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send message from a form using JavaMail. Try to follow this: http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/jsp/threads/324513/send-message-from-a-form-using-javamail.

But I got the same exception saying:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1984)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:656)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.lsp.service.Mailer.send(Mailer.java:50)
    at com.lsp.web.ContactServlet.doPost(ContactServlet.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.lsp.web.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:301)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1950)
    ... 29 more
```

In the website I provided, user kroken said "a SMTP server is missing according to the first line." Where can I get a SMTP server?

Comment: Ask your internet provider, that's the simplest way (every single ISP I know offers an SMTP server for use by their customers)

Comment: OK, but someone have suggested to download Apache James though.

Comment: As direct delivery of email off your own mailserver is becoming nearly impossible for spam-fighting reasons you can set up a mail server if you really want, but you'll be only able to use it as a relay that forwards to your ISP's smtp server.  So, unless you feel like you need your own relay eg because you have dozens of own servers running and want to streamline their traffic and configuration, running your own outgoing smtp server isn't that useful at all in 99% of the cases.

Comment: What is the best way to approach?

Comment: Just use your ISP's SMTP server

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to download anything or configure smtp server in Tomcat?

Comment: Or use a free server like Gmail or Yahoo Mail.

Comment: So, I just define smtp server in Servlet right?

Comment: Yes, that's right - just make sure Javamail knows where to find the external SMTP server, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Sending mail from local mail server is not an ideal way (Gmail/Yahoo will treated that as a SPAM).
You can use your web mail account( or google apps).
If you don't have control panel access (you can create your email account here) of your web site you can use gmail/yahoo account credentials to send mail.

Here is a sample mail application to send email using gmail and/or webmail account.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/71lwjamvg05cbhq/GmailAndWebMailSMTP.rar